# "How are you doing?" Why do we answer "good" instead of "well"?

Tags: colloquial-language

When someone asks me "How are you doing?"

Why do we answer "good" instead of "well" (adv. for doing) ?

Comment: In British English it is a fairly recent innovation. I personally would answer "well".  Under influence from America, I think younger people tend more and more to reply with "good". It seems wrong to me but usage changes.

Comment: A (partial) answer to this question is buried in the linked duplicate, perhaps it's better to write it as its own separate answer here.

Comment: I usually respond “I’m doing well, how are you?” I sometimes respond “Can’t complain, how about you?” Or “Fantastic! How are you?” Or “I’ve been better. You?” or many other ways depending on how I’m feeling and who I’m talking to.